# Push notification Token generation may take more time than expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented push notifications in a project, and I am getting the push notification tokens correctly. I am sending this tokens with login api.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication* )application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData* )deviceToken
{
    NSString *devToken = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
        [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    devToken = [devToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"token: %@",devToken);

    self.pushNotificationToken = devToken;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:devToken forKey:@"PushToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

I am getting token perfectly. But some time I think it may take some more time to generate a token. Because of the login api does not contain token. I have checked database stored the token. Some time it is `NULL`. When I logout and login then the database contains the token and works perfectly. What is the perfect way to sending push token to server?

Comment: where do you check database?

Comment: There is no specific time that you'll get your token, it may take 2ms/2seconds or a minute you never know. The right approach is whenever you receive a token then send it to your server in a separate api not in the login api.

Comment: @Hexfire our mysql db.where we stored tokens.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore i was thinking same, thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after experimenting this scenario push token generation may take anytime.There is not specific time duration. Mostly it will generate when app launches but we can not ensure.So better call api when we get token in delegate

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication* )application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData* )deviceToken
{
    NSString *devToken = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
        [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    devToken = [devToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"token: %@",devToken);

     //Call API to Update Device Token
}
```

Call the api to update token when token generated.